# How to get CSS style value in C# code behind?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

In ASP.NET code behind, I can add `css` style to an element by using this command:

```
elementID.Style.Add("padding", "20px");
```

BUT after adding this `css` property into `elementID`, how do I get access this property next time in code behind?

Comment: Define “next time”?

Comment: I mean, i want to get the value after a postback request.

Comment: Get the value via jquery.

Comment: Well then you have to _send_ it back to the server.

Comment: @misorude Can you suggest me some code in this case?

Comment: The HTML document or the CSS is not sent back in any situation. Could you explain why you need this, as in what are you trying to accomplish? This seems like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Style property is of type `CssStyleCollection`, which itself wraps a collection of the style attributes applied to the web control.
So basically, `string padding = elementID.Style["padding"];` is what you need.

Comment: This is not correct.

Comment: @dmeglio It is, objectively. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.cssstylecollection?view=netframework-4.7.2
Also please take the effort to elaborate when you point out something is incorrect.

Comment: The op asked for it to survive a post back. This does not. Hence it is incorrect.